# GraphQL fetchMore pagination with multiple queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a page that contains several horizontal scrolling lists of items (let's call them blog posts, or whatever). I want each list to have pagination, but I don't want to make *n* HTTP requests when the page loads, and I also don't want to re-request the other lists when I'm loading the next page of results for one of them.

Here's what the query looks like:

```
const QUERY = gql`
  query Sections(
    $favoritesOffset: Int = 0
    $featuredOffset: Int = 0
    $recentOffset: Int = 0
  ) {
    favorites: events(limit: 5, offset: $favoritesOffset, search: "FAVORITES") {
      ...listResponse
    }
    featured: events(limit: 5, offset: $featuredOffset, search: "FEATURED") {
      ...listResponse
    }
    recent: events(limit: 10, offset: $recentOffset, search: "RECENT") {
      ...listResponse
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm currently using Apollo client & server.

I want to be able to make one request for all 3 lists when the page loads and then use `fetchMore` to only load the next page of one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, my solution is to create one top-level query that contains all sections and then additional queries for the paginated responses of each section, then merged the data from the additional queries.

Using components makes this a bit cleaner.

## Simplified example:

**Parent.tsx** - With top-level query:

```
const QUERY = gql`
  query Sections(
    $favoritesOffset: Int = 0
    $featuredOffset: Int = 0
    $recentOffset: Int = 0
  ) {
    favorites: events(limit: 5, offset: $favoritesOffset, search: "FAVORITES") {
      ...listResponse
    }
    featured: events(limit: 5, offset: $featuredOffset, search: "FEATURED") {
      ...listResponse
    }
    recent: events(limit: 10, offset: $recentOffset, search: "RECENT") {
      ...listResponse
    }
  }
  ${LIST_RESPONSE}
`;

const Page = () => {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(QUERY);

  return (
    <>
      <Section initialData={results. favorites} search="FAVORITES" />
      <Section initialData={results. featured} search="FEATURED" />
      <Section initialData={results. recent} search="RECENT" />
    </>
  }
}
```

**Section.tsx**

```
const FETCH_MORE = gql`
  query SectionsFetchMore($search: String, $offset: Int, $limit: Int = 10) {
    ...listResponse
  }
  ${LIST_RESPONSE}
`;


const Section = ({search, initialData}) => {
  const { data: fetchedData, fetchMore } = useQuery(FETCH_MORE, {
    skip: true, // IMPORTANT
    variables: { search, limit: 10, offset: 0 },
  });


  const fetchNextPage = useCallback(async (nextOffset) => {
    await fetchMore({ variables: { offset: nextOffset } });

    // Then merge data, either:
    //  + use client.cache.updateQuery() to update parent cache
    //  + keep local state that combines initialData and fetchedData
  }, [fetchMore]);

  return (
    // ... display list ...
  );
};
```

## Merging

In my case, I merged the cache locally to keep things simple:

```
  const data = useMemo(() => {
    if (!fetchedData?.sections) {
      return initialData;
    }
    return {
      nodes: [...initialData.nodes, ...fetchedData?.sections?.nodes],
      pageInfo: fetchedData.sections.pageInfo,
    };
  }, [fetchedData, initialData]);
```

But, you could also update the apollo cache using `client.cache.updateQuery()` ([more info](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-updatequery-and-updatefragment)).